# Xaml editor Intellisense error with Multibinding Binding Path

Tags: xaml, data-binding, binding, visual-studio-2019, multibinding

I have a DataGrid with a DataGridCheckBoxColumn using Multibinding. The code compiles and works just as expected BUT intellisense in the XAML editor stops working as soon as I use the Path keyword in the markup.. It only stops for everything past the Binding tags but works prior to that:

```
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="colIssues" Width="sizetoheader" Header="Issues" >
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Binding>
                <MultiBinding  Converter="{StaticResource MultiBooleanConverter}">
                    <Binding  Path="Level"/>
                    <Binding  Path="Weeping" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Binding>
        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

**BEFORE**

[image: Snapshot of Intellisense working BEFORE the Path keyword]

**AFTER** now intellisense has disappeared

[image: AFTER]

Comment: I would like to add, that it is for any column type and any converter (even x:null) and any *string literal*  value of `Path` - it works for `Path="{x:Null}"` or path from resources. Moreover, in my case Intelisense does not work in whole file not just after binding.